# How to connect XML API into PHP Code

Tags: php, xml, api

I'm new developer, I need to connect XML API Hotel, In the documentation is mentioned about Startup guide, first we need to add customer login and user, there're two steps at first, but I don't know how to use them, and how to connect **Main XML URL** into PHP using the password login info like below:

**General Request / Request Format:**

```
    <customer>  
    <username>username</username>  
    <password>md5(password)</password>  
    <id>company code</id>  
    <source>1</source>  
    <request command="getallcities">  
        <return>  
            <filters>  
                <countryCode></countryCode>  
                <countryName></countryName>  
            </filters>  
            <fields>  
                <field>countryName</field>  
                <field>countryCode</field>  
            </fields>  
        </return>  
    </request>  
</customer>
```

**General Response / Response Format:**

```
    <result command=" " date="" ip="">  
    <request>  
        <error>  
            <class></class>  
            <code>error code</code>  
            <details></details>  
            <extraDetails></extraDetails>  
            <postXml></postXml>  
        </error>  
        <successful>FALSE</successful>  
    </request>  
</result>
```

**General Request XSD**

getallcities.xsd

I highly appreciate of someone will guide me how to use them and how to connect PHP into Main XML Url.

I highly appreciate your help in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, you didn't give very much to work with, but I'm going to try and help you solve this.

First off, let's use a PHP package to simplify converting an array into valid XML. It will save you time down the road. I recommend [Spatie's Array to Xml package](https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml).

If you're familiar with composer, go ahead and install that. If you've never used composer, go ahead and download src/ArrayToXml.php and put it in your project. (**I highly recommend you use composer if you don't, I'm just providing some extra instructions since I don't know your level of experience.**)

Now, I'm going to assume you got the Array To Xml package set up. Let's go ahead and structure an array before we convert it to xml.

```
// Structure the payload as an array and pass in any data you need dynamically
$payload = [
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'md5(password)',
  'id' => 'company code',
  'source' => '1',
  'request' => [
    'return' => [
      'filters' =>  [
        'countryCode' => [],
        'countryName' => [],
      ],
      'fields' => [
        'field' => [
          'countryName',
          'countryCode',
        ],
      ],
    ],
    '@attributes' => [
      'command' => 'getallcities',
    ],
  ],
];

// Convert the array to xml with a root of 'customer'
$xml = \Spatie\ArrayToXml\ArrayToXml::convert($payload, 'customer');
```

From there, we're going to initiate a curl call to the endpoint with your payload.

```
// Set the url you're making an api call to
$endpoint = 'https://yoursite.com/your-endpoint';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Content-Type: application/xml"
    ]
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($error) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $error;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Now you'll want to parse the response xml back into an array so you can process it. I created a package to help you do this. You can find it here: https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

The basic premise of installing it is the same. You'll do `$response = \Mtownsend\XmlToArray\XmlToArray::convert($response);`

See how that works.